# Drop down button or new dialog

Tags: usability, users, modal-windows, software

I need to give the users the possibly to browse for a template in the program or on the computer. Which of the shown ways do you think is the best way?

[image: Which of the ideas do you think is most user friendly?]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the next steps:
**The left one** let's me change my decision again and again since it's always on top of what we are doint
**The right one** is part of a (sort of)  wizard with selected steps (in a way) I select where to find my template and go on the next step, and going back to change my decision will take a lot more effort

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need drop-down for only two choices? Instead of browse button you can have label "Templates" and then two buttons:

1. Program
2. From computer